# How to define ActiveMQ component in format of JMS Component in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel 2.11.1. It seems that both xml definitions are not equivalent in Camel:

First definition:

```
<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent"
    p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" p:transacted="true"
    p:cacheLevelName="CACHE_CONSUMER" p:concurrentConsumers="20"
    p:maxConcurrentConsumers="500" p:idleConsumerLimit="10" />
```

Second definition:

```
<bean id="amq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"
    p:configuration-ref="jmsConfig" p:transacted="true" p:cacheLevelName="CACHE_CONSUMER" />

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="nakedConnectionFactory"
    p:concurrentConsumers="20" p:maxConcurrentConsumers="500"
    p:idleConsumerLimit="10" />

<bean id="nakedConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
    p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />
```

Since the first definition works well on the following route, but the second doesn't.

```
<route>
    <from uri="amq:example.MyQueue" />
    <setHeader headerName="myRoutingSlipHeader">
        <constant>amq:one#amq:two#amq:three#amq:four</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <log message="Makan" />
    <setExchangePattern pattern="InOut" />
    <routingSlip uriDelimiter="#">
        <header>myRoutingSlipHeader</header>
    </routingSlip>
    <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly" />
    <log message="End: ${body}" />
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="amq:one" />
    <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepOne" />
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="amq:two" />
    <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepTwo" />
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="amq:three" />
    <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepThree" />
</route>

<route>
    <from uri="amq:four" />
    <to uri="bean:helloBean?method=stepFour" />
</route>
```

The second component definition causes hang during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me. I did have to override the spring version with the created archetype. But I used this and it worked fine.

Please find my example project here :
https://github.com/jimternet/camel-activemq

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="true"
    persistent="false">
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </transportConnectors>
</broker>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true" />
        <to uri="activemq:personnel.records" />
    </route>
    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:personnel.records" />
        <log message="${body}" />

        <choice>
            <when>
                <xpath>/person/city = 'London'</xpath>
                <to uri="file:target/messages/uk" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <to uri="file:target/messages/others" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>


<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"
    p:configuration-ref="jmsConfig" p:transacted="true" p:cacheLevelName="CACHE_CONSUMER" />

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration"
    p:connectionFactory-ref="nakedConnectionFactory"
    p:concurrentConsumers="20" p:maxConcurrentConsumers="500"
    p:idleConsumerLimit="10" />

<bean id="nakedConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
    p:brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" />
```

Comment: The problem raises when you use inOut pattern.